# Save object clone as protected property

Tags: php, this, clone, self

I intend to create a clone of an object's parent within the constructor of that parent. In short:

```
class ParentClass {
    protected $property;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->property = clone $this;
    }
}

class ChildClass extends ParentClass {

}
```

This works all fine, yet the problem with this code is the protected property getting populated with an instance of the ChildClass, in case the ChildClass is instantiated. I would however like it to be an instance of the ParentClass regardless of the class `$this` refers to.

I could of course combine `debug_backtrace` and `new self()` (in order to avoid endless recursion of constructor invocations) and assign the resulting ParentClass instance to the property, though such a soluation is verbose, as debug backtrace only returns string names of caller classes and methods.

Lastly, I could combine `new self()` and the provision of an argument to the instantiation of the object indicating if a "new self" should be created, but I dislike the solution because of its ugliness and redundancy.

Is there a way in PHP to find a "clone of self"?

Comment: What is it you are actually trying to achieve with this? Why would an object need a clone of itself as a member, and in what sense would it be a clone if it was a different class? The conventional reading of this would be that "ChildClass is-a ParentClass" and "ChildClass has-a ParentClass", but for some reason *not* "ChildClass has-a ChildClass"... I suspect there is a less mind-bending way of doing whatever this is intended to achieve.

Comment: @IMSoP My message logger object can be extended by other objects. Any "public" message logger (which any script may instantiate) needs its own, private message logger as well, in order to log its own - for example - error messages. Now when I instantiate a mail logger, which inherits from the base message logger, I don't want the private message logger to be of the mail logger type but rather preserve the basic message logger type.

Comment: In that case, perhaps the "internal logger" should not be the base class in the first place, but a completely different object. You could have an abstract `PublicLogger` class, part of whose definition was to instantiate a `PrivateLogger` object (or have it provided in the constructor, as in "Dependency Injection"). Even without the internal logger, a mail logger has no business inheriting from a "basic" (log-to-file?) logger, rather than them both having a common `abstract` base or `interface`.

Comment: Alternatively, forget the whole notion of an internal logger, and just have a `protected` method such as `log_internal_logging_error` on the (abstract) base logger class for whatever last-ditch error-handling or debugging a logger would need to log.

Comment: @IMSoP The message logger logs the messages and may do certain things with them (depending on the flags that have been set on the object). Finally it can export the messages in a certain way if asked to. The same goes for the mail logger, albeit that certain methods on it have been slightly modified. I often inject an instance of the basic message logger in classes that need their own errors logged. To me it makes sense if I do the same for the message logger class itself.

Comment: Remember that unlike an `interface`, an `abstract class` can include implementation. So the shared logic for *preparing* messages can go into an abstract base class, but *any* logic for actually storing/delivering those messages belongs in a particular implementation. `MailLogger` is a sibling of `FileLogger`, not a child. If *every* logger has an internal logger, then those internal loggers must also have internal loggers, and so on, recursively. Separating "base class" from "simple implementation" allows an implementation that *doesn't* have an internal logger, and the problem goes away.

Comment: I don't understand why you simply don't use  `parent::yourMethod()` instead of cloning or creating interface. The `parent` holds the class and its properties and methods exactly as you need. Your children class may change the properties or completely redefine the methods...

Comment: @lp1051 I think the problem is that they're trying to put the logic *in* the parent class, so it is `self`, not `parent`. And obviously calling `new self()` in the constructor would lead to an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in the comments, I think the reason this pattern is not working for you is that you have a poorly designed object hierarchy. In the example, `ChildClass` is a "type of" `ParentClass`, but also internally references a copy of `ParentClass` to do some delegated work.

From the comments, what you have must look something like this:

```
class BasicLogger {
    protected $delegated_logger;

    public function __construct() {
         // initialise $this->delegated_logger somehow
    }

    public function logMessage($message, $flags) {
    {
         $prepared_message = $this->prepareMessage($message, $flags);
         $this->deliverMessage($prepared_message);
    }

    private function prepareMessage($message, $flags) {
         // implementation here
    }

    protected function deliverMessage($prepared_message) {
         // implementation here
    }
}

class MailLogger extends BasicLogger {
    protected function deliverMessage($prepared_message) {
         // different implementation here
         if ( $mail_sending_failed ) {
             $this->delegated_logger->logMessage('Oops, MailLogger failed...');
         }
    }
}
```

However, `BasicLogger` is actually performing multiple roles in the object hierarchy:

1. defining the interface that all loggers should adhere to (here represented as a single `logMessage` method)
2. providing a shared implementation of `prepareMessage` that all loggers will use, and an implementation of `logMessage` that depends on it plus a `deliverMessage` function
3. providing a specific implementation of `deliverMessage` that will be completely over-written by child classes
4. providing a mechanism for complex implementations to delegate to simpler implementations, without a way of distinguishing between the two

The first three roles should be separated into an `interface`, an `abstract` base class, and a simple implementation:

```
interface Logger {
    public function logMessage($message, $flags = null);
}

abstract class BaseLogger implements Logger {
    public function logMessage($message, $flags = null) {
    {
         $prepared_message = $this->prepareMessage($message, $flags);
         $this->deliverMessage($prepared_message);
    }

    private function prepareMessage($message, $flags) {
         // implementation here
    }

    abstract protected function deliverMessage($prepared_message);
}

class BasicTextLogger extends BaseLogger {
    protected function deliverMessage($prepared_message) {
         // implementation here
    }
}
```

You can then use instances of `BasicTextLogger` wherever you need, including in other implementations of `BaseLogger`.

You might want to put the logic of having a delegated logger (the 4th role of my `BasicLogger` above) into another class for reuse. `BasicTextLogger` shouldn't inherit this behaviour, or you'll end up needing to provide a logger to a logger to a logger to a logger, *ad infinitum*.

```
 abstract class ComplexLogger extends BaseLogger {
     protected $delegated_logger;

     public function __construct( Logger $delegated_logger ) {
         if ( $delegated_logger instanceOf ComplexLogger ) {
              throw new Exception('Attempted to delegate one complex logger to another; danger of recursion, so disallowed.');
         } else {
              $this->delegated_logger = $delegated_logger;
         }
     }
 }

 class MailLogger extends ComplexLogger {
     protected function deliverMessage($prepared_message) {
         // different implementation here
         if ( $mail_sending_failed ) {
             $this->delegated_logger->logMessage('Oops, MailLogger failed...');
         }
     }
 }
```

This then allows you to perform Dependency Injection to provide your complex logger with a simple logger to delegate to:

```
 $my_logger = new MailLogger( new BasicTextLogger() );
 $my_logger->logMessage('Hello World!');
```

This may seem like a lot of different `class`es and `interface`s, but each now has a clear responsibility. You could put the whole `$delegated_logger` logic into `MailLogger`, but you'd have to copy and paste it if you had another complex logger later. You might also be able to ignore the `Logger` interface, and just type-hint for classes deriving from the `BaseLogger` class, but it's possible you'll want an implementation that doesn't use `prepareMessage` at all - for instance, a `DoNothingLogger`.

Comment: If anyone can think of better terms to use in place of `Base` and `Basic`, let me know, as the distinction between the two is kind of crucial to this answer.